# How to extract on-screen area on XD of an image

Tags: adobe-xd, zeplin

I just received the XD file from the designer, now am trying to extract the nav area image from the canvas but image is too spread out from the canvas how it can be cropped to the area of the nav.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Adobe Photoshop To Resize them to Fit Original image
or
if you want part of image you can use one of image magnify plugins first

they will fit image to canvas

then use export
Also you can use Web Export Plugins